# How to understand the specific meaning of ‘const’ when it is in different positions

Tags: c

The following examples are listed.

1. `const int a`
2. `int const a`
3. `const int *a`
4. `int* const a`
5. `int const* a const`

Comment: [The clockwise/spiral rule](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clockwise-spiral-rule-in-c-c-with-examples/#:~:text=The%20Spiral%2FClockwise%20Method%20is,how%20to%20apply%20this%20method.) might be good to know.

Comment: Try https://cdecl.org/

Comment: 1 and 2 are equivalent. Regarding the rest, see the linked FAQ.